# how to reach to goal an end point with obstacle

Tags: python, ros, robotics

Here is the controller python script(controller.py). How to achieve to a certain goal(reach an end point)?

This has an basic obstacle (a wall).

Just no started ros, a very beginner on this. Great learning so far, what mistake am i making ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry

from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion

import math

def Waypoints(t):
    x  = 0.2
    y  = 4
    return [x,y]

def control_loop():
    rospy.init_node('ebot_controller')

    pub = rospy.Publisher('/cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=10)
    rospy.Subscriber('/ebot/laser/scan', LaserScan, laser_callback)
    rospy.Subscriber('/odom', Odometry, odom_callback)

    rate = rospy.Rate(10) 

    velocity_msg = Twist()
    velocity_msg.linear.x = 0
    velocity_msg.angular.z = 0
    pub.publish(velocity_msg)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        velocity_msg = Twist()
        velocity_msg.linear.x = x 
        velocity_msg.angular.z = y
        pub.publish(velocity_msg)
        print("Controller message pushed at {}".format(rospy.get_time()))
        rospy.spin()
        rate.sleep()

def odom_callback(data):
    global pose
    x  = data.pose.pose.orientation.x;
    y  = data.pose.pose.orientation.y;
    z = data.pose.pose.orientation.z;
    w = data.pose.pose.orientation.w;
    pose = [data.pose.pose.position.x, data.pose.pose.position.y, euler_from_quaternion([x,y,z,w][2]]

def laser_callback(msg):
    global regions
    regions = {
        'bright':min(min(msg.ranges[300:420], 10),
        'fright':min(min(msg.ranges[144:287]), 10),
        'front':min(min(msg.ranges[288:431]), 10),
        'fleft':min(min(msg.ranges[432:575]), 10),
        'bleft':min(min(msg.ranges[300:420], 10),
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        control_loop()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

How to achieve to a certain goal(reach an end point)?

Thank you.

Comment: "How to achieve to a certain goal(reach an end point)?" -- what have you tried so far? besides, how is the wall specified? Also, is this homework?

Comment: not an homework, just learning ros for the first time, this is my personal project

Comment: How to you want to move your robot. E.g. with a pose and let the system plan and execute a path or do you want to use other predefined ways or do you want to implement your own excution program?

Answer (score 0):

Because if you just want your robot to move to the goal position you can use movebase. Movebase provides an action server with the name `move_base/goal` their you send your goals it plans the path global and executes it local by taking live time sensor values into account. See this side for help: http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals